# solve the linear problem with graphic method.

Tags: linear-programming

\begin{equation} 
2x_1 + 3x_2 \geq 6
\\-5x_1 + 9x_2 \leq 12
\\ 2x_1 - 3x_2 \leq 6
\\ x_1 + x_2 \leq 5
\\ 0 \leq x_1 \leq 4
\\ 0 \leq 2x_2 \leq 5
\\ \min z = -3x_1 - 2x_2
\end{equation}

solve the linear problem with graphic method.

I found this problem in my book but I couldn't solve that. Anyone can help me? Thankss..

Comment: What can't you do ?

Comment: Here is a graphical solution. Just use the slider :-)
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3eq0j0cnen